# `angular-cli` getting warning while access the images from assets

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I access the images, through home components native css file, `home.component.scss` I am getting follwing warnings. how to prevents this? or what is wrong with my code?

I am using `Angular CLI: 1.7.4` any one help me?

here is my `scss` code :

`a.get-price{
            background:url("assets/images/icons/svg/icon-calc.svg") no-repeat center;
        }`

here is the warning:

`[WDS] Warnings while compiling.`

```
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) postcss-url: C:\DHL\Projects\retailApp\src\app\pages\home\home.component.scss:103:3: Can't read file 'C:\DHL\Projects\retailApp\src\app\pages\home\assets\images\icons\svg\icon-location.svg', ignoring
 @ ./src/app/pages/home/home.component.ts 22:21-53
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just changed my url from

`background:url("assets/images/icons/svg/icon-calc.svg") no-repeat center;`

to ( added a slash before assets )

`background:url("/assets/images/icons/svg/icon-calc.svg") no-repeat center;`

works fine.